# Changing image of a node based on JSON data it contains with vis.js without DataSet being defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, vis.js

I'm working with Vis.js in a django project. I have a network created and I need to be able to to have nodes images change based on the JSON data they hold. I'm having issues doing this because of the whole DataSet needing to be defined in order to use nodes.update etc. I'm unable to predefine the nodes as it's based on the return of another object so the number of nodes are random. The node and edge properties are added in a Django view.

Here's my code:

Django snibbet:

```
@login_required
def project_detail(request, project_id):
    """
    Project detail, include graphical representation: modules in this project
    :param request:
    :param project_id:
    :return:
    """
    all_edges = request.GET.get('all_edges', '')
    draw_invisible_button = ''

    network_nodes = []
    network_edges = []
    tc_keys = []
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)

    testcases = project.testcaseresults_set.latest('updated').results

    user = request.user
    user.humanresource.project = project
    user.humanresource.save()
    for tc in testcases:
        data = tc['data']
        tc_keys.append(data)

    for m in project.modules:
        network_nodes.append({
            'id': m.id,
            'label': m.name,
        })
    for d, n in zip(network_nodes, tc_keys):
        d['data'] = n

    for edge in project.edges_between_modules:
        try:
            if edge.properties[EDGE_TYPES_INVISIBLE_KEY] == 'on':
                draw_invisible_button = 'true'
                if not all_edges:
                    continue
        except KeyError:
            pass

        if not check_edge_in_set(edge, network_edges):
            network_edges.append({
                'id': edge.id,
                'to': edge.to_node.module.id,
                'from': edge.from_node.module.id,
                'label': 1,
                'edge_name': edge.from_node.name + '-' + edge.to_node.name,

                'type': edge.type.name,
                'to_node': edge.to_node.name,
                'from_node': edge.from_node.name,
                'priority': edge.priority,
                'properties': edge.properties
            })

    context = {
        'projects': projects,
        'project': project,
        'all_edges': all_edges,
        'draw_invisible_button': draw_invisible_button,

        'module_new_form': ModuleForm(project_id=project.id),
        'module_import_form': UploadForm(),
        'edge_types': EdgeType.objects.all(),
        'edge_priority': Edge.PRIORITY_CHOICES,

        'network_nodes': json.dumps(network_nodes),
        'network_edges': json.dumps(network_edges),

        'edges_between_modules': network_edges
    }

    return render(request, 'graphs/project/project_detail.html', context)
```

Template nodes and edges reference snibbet:

```
<script>
        var nodes = {{ network_nodes|safe }};
        var edges = {{ network_edges|safe }};
</script>
```

This is an example of what the nodes JSON array looks like:

```
[{"id": 1540, "data": [], "label": "AccountFound"}, {"id": 1541, "data": [], "label": "AccountNotFound"}, {"id": 1542, "data": [], "label": "AddANI"}, {"id": 1543, "data": [], "label": "AutoPay"}, {"id": 1544, "data": [], "label": "AutoPayAccount"}, {"id": 1545, "data": [{"tcs_cannot_route": "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found", "title": "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'GreetingDefault'"}, {"tcs_cannot_route": "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found", "title": "Route from 'DNISGreeting' to 'HOOCheck'"}, {"tcs_cannot_route": "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found", "title": "Route from 'GreetingDefault' to 'HOOCheck'"}, {"tc_steps": [{"content": "APN: 8552929487, HollyBrowser: , ", "expected": ""}], "title": "Route from 'Start' to 'GetCallerDetail'", "pre_conditions": []}, {"tcs_cannot_route": "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found", "title": "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'DNISGreeting'"}], "label": "Start - Greeting"}, {"id": 1546, "data": [], "label": "Transfer"}]
```

This is my drawfunction:

```
function draw_project_graph() {

    // create a network
    var container = document.getElementById('module_in_project');

    //var nodes = new vis.DataSet("{{ network_nodes|escapejs }}");

    // provide the data in the vis format
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };
    var options = {
        nodes: {
            shape: 'image',
            image: image_url + 'blue-infrastructure-graphics_11435264594_o.png',
            //image: image_url + 'west-ivr-graphic_11435724503_o.png',
            size: 25
        },
        edges: {
            color: '#000',
            length: 190,
            arrows: 'to',
            arrowStrikethrough: false
        },
        width: '100%',
        height: '800px'
    };

    // initialize your network!
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

    var n = JSON.stringify("{{ network_nodes|escapejs }}");
    var node = JSON.parse(n);
    console.log(node);
    $.each(JSON.parse(node), function(idx, obj){
        var details = obj.data;
        var id = obj.id;
        for (var i = 0; i < details.length; ++i){
            for(var ind in details[i]){
                if(ind === 'tcs_cannot_route'){
                    console.log(id);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    network.on('click', function(params){
        //console.log(params.nodes)
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(params.nodes)) {
            var current = '',
                tmp = window.location.href.split('/');
            for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length - 3; i++) {
                current += tmp[i] + '/'
            }
            $('#module_in_project').css('cursor', 'progress');
            window.location.href = current + 'project_module_detail/' + params.nodes;

        } else if (!$.isEmptyObject(params.edges)){
            //console.log(params.edges)
            $('a[href="#projectEdges"]').click();
            $('a[href="#project-edge-{0}"]'.format(params.edges)).click();
            $('.edges-between-modules').show();
            $('.edges-between-modules-contents').hide();
        } else {
            $('a[href="#projectModules"]').click();
        }
    })
}
```

I need to change:

```
image: image_url + 'blue-infrastructure-graphics_11435264594_o.png',
```

To:

```
image: image_url + 'yellow-infrastructure-graphics_o.png',
```

When "data": [] contains 'tcs_cannot_route' and only the effected node the other nodes need to remain the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Of course this was on my mind over the weekend and I solved it right away this morning by making a small change in my template.

from:

```
<script>
        var nodes = {{ network_nodes|safe }};
        var edges = {{ network_edges|safe }};
</script>
```

to:

```
<script>
        var nodes = new vis.DataSet({{ network_nodes|safe }});
        var edges = new vis.DataSet({{ network_edges|safe }});
</script>
```

Then in my $.each I was able to add nodes.update()

```
$.each(JSON.parse(node), function(idx, obj){
        var details = obj.data;
        var id = obj.id;
        for (var i = 0; i < details.length; ++i){
            for(var ind in details[i]){
                if(ind === 'tcs_cannot_route'){
                    console.log(id);
                    **nodes.update([{id:id, image: image_url + 'yellow-infrastructure-graphics_o.png'}])**
                }
            }
        }
    });
```